# Number less than 0

Tags: lua

Im trying to set the counter to 0 if counterFlag[name] is less than 0.

```
if counterFlag[name] <== 0 then
counterFlag[name] = 0

end
```

How could I do that?

I get the ''unexpected symbol'' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
if counterFlag[name] < 0 then
    counterFlag[name] = 0
end
```

Or use `<=` for less than or equal to, it has the same effect in this scenario.

Comment: And now I get the ''attempt to compare __lt on nil and number'' error.

Comment: this means that "name" is nil

Comment: @user3142039 Check the value of `counterFlag[name]`, its value now is `nil`, you can't compare `nil` with a number.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you actually want to set the counter to 0 if it is not a number greater than 0.

```
counterFlag[name] = 
    type(counterFlag[name]="number") 
    and (counterFlag[name] > 0) 
    and counterFlag[name]
  or 0
```

`and` is an operator that returns its first effectively false operand, otherwise its last operand.
`or` is an operator that returns its first effectively true operand, otherwise its last operand.

Effectively false means having a value of `nil` or `false`.
Effectively true means the opposite.

So the first part conditionally keeps the same value and the second part gives 0 if the conditions aren't met.

---

Alternatively, a Lua idiom is often used to initialize a variable that *might* be `nil`:

```
counterFlag[name] = counterFlag[name] or 0
```

You could put this before code that uses `counterFlag[name]` so it then wouldn't have to check for `nil`. And, because, presumably, you wouldn't have assigned any other non-number value, the code could use operators that require number values without checking for that.

---

See [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html).